# Access javascript object in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I access the javascript object which is available when I use browser console in vuejs component. I am using a javascript library. I added the javascript script in index.html which created the javascript object in DOM. But I am not able to access the object directly in vuejs.

```
  <head>
    <script
    id="fsc-api"
    src="https://d1f8f9xcsvx3ha.cloudfront.net/sbl/0.8.0/fastspring-builder.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"
    data-storefront="fastspringexamples.test.onfastspring.com/popup-fastspringexamples">
    </script>
 </head>
```

so I can see the object **fastspring** in browser console window but when I am directly using this object in vuejs component its says fastspring is not defined. However, if I console.log this object from component I can see the object in browser console.

Comment: which javascript object you are referring to? be more elaborate on the issue

Comment: its a plain javascript object which was created while initializing the library using above script in head tag. Actually I am using javascript library inside vuejs.

Comment: did yu try console.log the same object. what do yu get?. try window.<nameofobject> otherwise

Comment: @khaleel thanks, yes I am able to get object with window.fastspring. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped. I have added it as answer. Kindly accept it as answer and upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as `window.<nameoftheobject>`